# Aligning two binary arrays Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking for an effective way to  align two 2D binary arrays in python. Each array represents a map and every position is a pixel of the map either occupied (1) or free (0) space. In order to evaluate these two maps, I need to align the data. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us what you've got so far

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you mean by "align"?

Comment: I want to rotate and translate one of the arrays so that the most points match the points of the ground truth array. I've constructed a piece of code which shifts the array left to right. Then I checked the difference between these two arrays and the shift with the smallest sum is then executed. The same goes for up and down and for rotation and then start all over again to get the smallest difference. But this method is time consuming.